# keycloak SPI for client policy?

Tags: java, keycloak

I'm trying to implement an `SPI` for a client policy to replace the policies I have in `js`.

I implemented `PolicyProvider` similar to [this](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/authz/policy/common/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authorization/policy/provider/role/RolePolicyProvider.java) and `PolicyProviderFactory` like [this](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/authz/policy/common/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authorization/policy/provider/role/RolePolicyProviderFactory.java), then I copy my `jar` to `standalone/deployments` as explained in [implementing an SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#implementing-a-spi)

I can see in the log that the jar has been deployed:

```
08:17:02,647 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) about to start org.keycloak.services.util.JsonConfigProvider$JsonScope@266abf6d                                                                             
08:17:02,682 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (MSC service thread 1-3) KC-SERVICES0047: myEvListener (example.myProvider.EvListenerProviderFactory) is implementing the internal SPI eventsListener. This SPI is internal and may change without notice                                                                                                                                                                               
08:17:02,692 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (MSC service thread 1-3) KC-SERVICES0047: myRolePolicy (example.myProvider.MyPolicyProviderFactory) is implementing the internal SPI policy. This SPI is internal and may change without notice                                                                                                                                                                                         
08:17:02,814 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "myPolicyProvider.jar" (runtime-name : "myPolicyProvider.jar")
```

Now I can't find a way to actually create a client policy using my `SPI`

[image: create policy]

In the server info I can see my policies (`my-role-policy` and `my-js-policy`) listed in policy providers:

[image: myPolicies]

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? Ran into a similar problem. Also how can I see the server info page? Please add info if you have fixed this.

Comment: I just added an answer to my question, the server info can be found at the top right corner, as can be seen in this screenshot https://i.imgur.com/Ifl7iTi.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a policy is required to make a POST request to:

```sh
http://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm}/clients/${clientId}/authz/resource-server/policy/${policyId}
```

where `policyId` is specified in `PolicyProviderFactory`

```
public String getId() {
    return "myId";
}
```

the body of your post should be a json

```
{
    "decisionStrategy": "AFFIRMATIVE",
    "logic": "POSITIVE",
    "name": "policyName",
    .... // other fields required in your policy implementation
}
```

a curl request example:

```sh
curl --request POST \
  --url http://${host}:${port}/auth/admin/realms/${realm}/clients/${clientId}/authz/resource-server/policy/${policyId} \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer ${token}' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"decisionStrategy": "AFFIRMATIVE","logic": "POSITIVE","name": "is-admin","role": "admin"}'
```

Comment: can you please share your SPI? I'm trying to implement the same thing pretty much, and I've managed to create a custom policy, and I can see it under "Create Policy..." dropdown, but when I try creating it (manually from admin console UI), Keycloak juts prompts me with "Page not found..." --- and that's fine I suppose as I haven't yet find a way to render the policy on UI (didn't create a template, form etc. and can't find docs on how to do so)